# Price Change Alert at custom level

Tags: magento-1.8, price, extensions

Are there any extensions which can do the following:

Customer subscribe to a product at $300, customer enter the desire amount (eg $200) if the product falls below $200, customer will get notification email.

Answer (score 3):

You need to check every time when product update using Magento event observer method.
**catalog_product_save_before**

```
<?php
class Namespace_Modulename_Model_Observer extends Varien_Event_Observer
{

    public function sendPriceNotice($observer)
    {
//While saving each product check your requirement and send email to required customers.
    }
}
```

Thank You.

Comment: This is good answer, i will try to implement it.

Comment: Accept your answer you found useful. so that others can refer it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this extension,
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/product-alert-info.html

It's not free but low price only 5 bucks ..

Comment: Can you put some relevant codes from the extension that is relevant to this question.? This is a link-only answer and it should be avoided !

Comment: @programmer_rkt yeah, but the question is like that. What can I do for that.?

Comment: I just point out integrity of your answer. If the link that you given become outdated in future, then there is no use with this answer. It will lost its meaning. So that is why we are always recommending to add relevant codes or give at least what that extension do exactly. Hope you will get what I mean

Comment: Hi the extension is like any price movement the subscriber will get email, but subscriber is not able to input their desire amount.